# animate.enter not firing from directive inside a view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created a custom directive that fires $animate.enter when its created. Works fine until I place the directive within a view. The only way I can get it work is to use a very long timeout or change the parent container to the body. Why?

This is the directive and animation

```
app.directive('ngCustom',  function ($animate, $timeout, $rootScope) {

  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var parent = element.parent();//angular.element(document.body);
    $timeout(function(){
      $animate.enter(element, parent);
    });
  }
});

app.animation('.animate-custom', [ function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj.enter = function(element){          
      TweenMax.from(element.find("h1"), 0.5, {delay:1, opacity:0, x:"+=100"});
    }
    return obj;
}]);
```

and a sample app with the directive inside a view

http://plnkr.co/edit/HEDUIAifPEB6TbKNdm48?p=preview

Comment: `ng-view` also has animation hooks for [enter](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.8/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L231) and [leave](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.8/src/ngRoute/directive/ngView.js#L208) that are likely to be conflicting with the enter hook used in your `ng-custom` directive. Setting your parent to the DOM body works because there aren't any animation hooks registered on it.

Comment: hmm, I dont think its as simple a conflict. Using addClass instead of the enter hook also causes the same issue, http://plnkr.co/edit/VIGYpOfu6QIknZJBKEKi?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

add ng-animate-children to ng-view

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10929#issuecomment-72396889